# Open Weather Map using Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a simple app that I can use to call (using REST services) the Open Weather Map (OWM) service to receive the JSON output and do various things with it. I am using Spring MVC framework in Eclipse and I am able to get a JSON output but everything I get comes out as NULL. I feel it has something to do with OWM not recognizing my API key from the way I am calling it. Any pointers would be great. I am also utilizing the OWM java library that is provided in the solutions and parters section on the OWM website.

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/current/{city}")
    public ResponseEntity currentWeather(@PathVariable("city") String city) throws MalformedURLException, JSONException, IOException{
    //String apiKey = "**myAPIKey**";
    OpenWeatherMap openWMap = new OpenWeatherMap("**myAPIKey**");
    openWMap.getApiKey();
    CurrentWeather currentW = openWMap.currentWeatherByCityName("Berlin");

    return new ResponseEntity(currentW, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

and my output looks like

```
{

"responseCode": -2147483648,
"rawResponse": null,
"dateTime": null,
"weatherCount": 0,
"cityName": null,
"coordInstance": null,
"mainInstance": null,
"rainInstance": null,
"sysInstance": null,
"windInstance": null,
"baseStation": null,
"cityCode": -9223372036854775808,
"cloudsInstance": null,
"valid": false
```

}

If I could figure out how to get a correct JSON response I feel as if I could get the temperature and what not with reasonable ease. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had a null value being returned due to a firewall at my work. Turned off the proxy and everything worked perfectly!